# Why won't my matrix convert from character to numeric?

Tags: r

I'm trying to normalise my data for use in a neural network. My data train0 has all integer or double type columns except for the last one which is a factor. This is what I've tried doing.

```
n <- ncol(train0)-1
y_train <- train0$ffail 
x_train <- as.matrix(train0[,4:n]) 

range_norm <- function(x) {
  ( (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)) )}
# Normalize training and test data
x_train_norm <- apply(x_train, 2, range_norm)
```

But I keep getting this error: `Error in x - min(x) : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

I've checked the type of each column in x_train and it says their all characters so I've tried converting to numeric like this

```
  for(i in 1:ncol(x_train)){
       x_train1[,i] <- as.numeric(x_train[,i])
       print(typeof(x_train1[,i]))
     }
```

However, after I use `as.numeric`, I print the type of each column to check and they're still characters.

I would appreciate any help in trying to normalise the data and how to convert the data to a numeric matrix. Thanks

Comment: A matrix can not have one column numeric and the other columns character. You have to do: `x_train <- as.numeric(x_train)`

Comment: if you do ```typeof(as.matrix(x_train))``` it's character?

Comment: if one of your columns is still character, when you coerce it into a matrix, all will default to character. do ```str(train0[,4:n])``` to see which is a character or factor

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm not sure what the problem was but I restarted R and now everything is running smoothly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to convert a `character` matrix to a `numeric` matrix:

```r
m = matrix(as.character(1:9), 3, 3)                                         

m                                                                           
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,] "1"  "4"  "7" 
## [2,] "2"  "5"  "8" 
## [3,] "3"  "6"  "9" 

apply(m, 2, as.numeric)                                                     
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    1    4    7
## [2,]    2    5    8
## [3,]    3    6    9
```

Comment: or `matrix(as.numeric(m), nrow(m))`

Answer (score 0):

We may set the storage `mode` of the matrix to `"numeric"`.

```
m <- matrix(as.character(1:9), 3, 3)       
                              
m
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "1"  "4"  "7" 
# [2,] "2"  "5"  "8" 
# [3,] "3"  "6"  "9" 

mode(m)
# [1] "character"

mode(m) <- "numeric"  ## set storage mode

m
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    4    7
# [2,]    2    5    8
# [3,]    3    6    9
```